# if statement without an else (when it seemingly needs one)

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm doing practice Java problems as a completely new beginner. I came across a problem where it uses a conditional if statement to satisfy one condition. If that condition is not met it proceeds without executing, and instead executes something else that is not in the if statement. However there is no else statement. I feel like I'm explaining this terribly so I will simply copy/paste the problem and the satisfactory code here.

PROBLEM:

Given a string, return a new string where the first and last chars have been exchanged.

EXAMPLES:

frontBack("code") → "eodc"

frontBack("a") → "a"

frontBack("ab") → "ba"

SATISFACTORY CODE:

```
public String frontBack(String str) {

   if(str.length() <= 1) return str;

   String mid = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);

   return str.charAt(str.length() - 1) + mid + str.charAt(0);  

}
```

As I pointed out before, there is no else statement but I feel like there should be. Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: *Why* do you think there needs to be an `else` statement? The rest of the method is effectively the "else" here...

Comment: Because the if statement contains a `return`, it will return immediately, so the rest of the method will never execute and you don't need an `else`

Comment: Thanks xdhmoore, didn't know exactly how return worked. that makes a LOT of sense now though and I don't know why I didn't think about that before, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `returning` from the method the rest of the code will not be executed:

```
if(str.length() <= 1) return str;
```

If `str.length()` is `<= 1` then the method will return right then and there and no other lines of code in the method will be executed...

Comment: @Steven This explanation pretty much applies to every programming language in the same "phylum" as Java.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as returning early.  In essence, your program does not need to continue its execution past the guard condition - if the length of the string is less than or equal to 1.  By virtue of the `return`, you bring back the string that you were provided to satisfy its clause and **no further execution of the method** is performed.

For most people, it's a code style decision; for others, it's a readability issue.  Some may believe that the form with the early `return` reads a bit better and would like to preserve that. If you were to write the code out with the `else`, it'd look something like this:

```
public String frontBack(String str) {
    if (str.length() <= 1) {
        return str;
    } else {
        String mid = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
        return str.charAt(str.length() - 1) + mid + str.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

It's an exercise in readability; if you think that the above form reads clearer, then use it; otherwise, the early return is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If I may, it's exactly equivalent of:

```
public String frontBack(String str)  {

   if(str.length() <= 1) 
   {
       return str;
   }
   else
   {
      String mid = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);

      return str.charAt(str.length() - 1) + mid + str.charAt(0);  
   }
}
```

In that case, the code you wrote is more readable

Answer (score 0):

if the string length is 1 or less, it will return immediately. It will not process the subsequent statements. The advantage of this is that it keeps code from getting indented too much

```
   if(str.length() <= 1) return str;

   String mid = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);

   return str.charAt(str.length() - 1) + mid + str.charAt(0);
```